# How to view masked IP adress and port?

Tags: ip, port

In my friends work place there is normally a broadband network and they PC's connect through Router and there is one website like this <10.1.1.7:9095> and i really wanna figure out what this website is any help? through port scanning or what can i use? remember i dont have direct access to that PC

Answer (score 2):

If it is a website, then why not use a web browser?

E.g. start Firefox, go to the URL line and type in `http://10.1.1.7:9095`

[image: Example]

Compare it to dialing someone with a phone, you either use an address book (in a browser it is a clicking on a link) or you dial a number. In web browser you 'dial' by typing in the location which you want to open.

In this case you want to open the web address 10.1.1.7 on port 9095, so you just type that in the browsers URL line and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This pc's IP address, `10.1.1.7`, falls into a class of addresses known as Class-A `private`, which means you can access them only from within the same LAN, `i.e.`, from your friend's work place. I take it this is what you mean when you say:

> remember i dont have direct access to that PC

It may or may not be possible to access that pc from outside that LAN (chances are it is not). If you want to understand what that pc is doing, first you ought to investigate the uses of port `9095` on Google: the short answer (for instance look [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)) is that there is no known application using that port, TCP or UDP.

Perhaps that address has a custom application waiting for connections on port 9095, and then Hennes' suggestion will work just fine. You can start gathering more info by running an `nmap` scan on the pc:

```
    sudo nmap -T2 -A 10.1.1.7
```

This is a tad slow, but you will alert fewer onlookers to your intentions this way. A fast command which cannot possibly go unnoticed would use `T5` instead.

It will recover much info, including whether other ports are open, and can be used to access the pc. In particular, it might even be able to tell (it does under certain circumstances) whether the application listening on port 9095 is a standard application, moved to an unused port for reasons of stealth, safety, or what not.

Comment: can i use nmap to see ip's that acess on 9095 if it is which command?

Comment: Are you asking if you can see the IP's that are connected to 10.1.1.7:9095? If so, yes, but not using nmap. You will have to use more sophisticated techniques, like arp-poisoning or packet sniffing.

Comment: lil explaining on packet sniffing btw i will be glad if u hit me at https://fb.me/iamnamrud

Comment: In addition: No you can not see the command which was used to connect to that IP:port unless you have access to the host which initiated that command.